# How to get Value in between a tag with HTMLParser

Tags: java, html, html-parsing

I am using HTMLParser (org.htmlparser) to parse HTML. I have used it to visit tags and get tag attributes like this one:

```
NodeVisitor linkvisitor = new NodeVisitor() {
    public void visitTag(Tag tag) {
        if ("script".equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
            String srcValue = tag.getAttribute("src");
            // do stuff 
        }
    }
        // How to get value instead of tag?     
}
```

However now I need to get the value in between a tag, say, the `<script>` tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not saying there is anything wrong with htmlparser but have you considered JSoup?

Comment: @Andrew, thanks for the hint. Just got to JSoup site, it looks like interesting, I will definitely look into it. After all, the design of my code I very loosely-coupled and I can switch from parser to parser. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you already know that the `Tag` is a script tag you should be able to cast it to a [`ScriptTag`](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/ScriptTag.html). Then you should be able to use the [`CompositeTag.getStringText()`](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/CompositeTag.html#getStringText%28%29).

```
NodeVisitor linkvisitor = new NodeVisitor() {
  public void visitTag(Tag tag) {
    if (tag.getTagName().equals("SCRIPT")) {
      ScriptTag script = (ScriptTag)tag;
      String srcValue = script.getAttribute("src");
      String text = script.getStringText();
    }
  }
};
```

See the [Javadocs for NodeVisitor](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/visitors/NodeVisitor.html) for a description about seting up the `visitTag` method.

If you are only concerned with tags that have end tags you can see if it is an instance of [CompositeTag](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/CompositeTag.html), otherwise the tag does not have an end tag (`<tag/>`). Then call the [getStringText()](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/htmlparser/tags/CompositeTag.html#getStringText%28%29) method I mentioned above.

```
if(tag instanceof CompositeTag) {
  CompositeTag cTag = (CompositeTag)tag;
  String text = cTag.getStringText();
}
```